# Foundation 6 menu icon been show on click link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, zurb-foundation

I have this top-bar menu using foundation 6 and scss on Rails 4.
The issue is that any time you click any link in the menu the menu icon (hamburger) appers and it shouldn't because is full screen, it also stop responding the onclick event in the hamburger icon. Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

```
               <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="top-bar-title">
                <div>
                   <%= link_to image_tag("logo.png", alt: "PeopleWare SRL"), page_path('index') %>
                </div>            
              <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
                <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div id="responsive-menu">
              <div class="top-bar-right">
                 <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
                    <li><%= link_to 'Blog', page_path('blog') %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Support", "http://soporte.peopleware.do" %></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
               </div>
        </div>
```

You can go and test the menu here: http://carey.peopleware.do

Comment: Unless you have an erb->HTML compilation issue, **only post the compiled HTML**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation responsive menu as of version 6 separates the title-bar from the top-bar and your markup does not reflect that update.  In order for the responsive menu to work, the toggle needs to be higher in the markup tree.  [Responsive Toggle](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html#responsive-toggle)

lines 28-56 of your compiled markup are:

```
 <section id="menu" class="menu">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
           <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="top-bar-title">
              <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
                <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
              </span>
                <div>
                   <a href="/index"><img alt="PeopleWare SRL" src="/assets/logo-345d236755fdd29efe4113717b59043034744758f71f11618e58672f2e0dbc6b.png" /></a>
                </div>            
            </div>
            <div id="responsive-menu">
              <div class="top-bar-right">
                 <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
                    <!--<li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="/index#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/jason">Software</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index#careers">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index#contact">Contact us</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="http://soporte.peopleware.do">Support</a></li>-->
                 </ul>
              </div>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

The top-bar-title div needs to be removed from the top-bar and renamed to title-bar-title (thank you Zurb for naming things).  This div needs to be in a div classed title-bar.  Also, your title-bar-title should not contain the button, or the png image.

So this:

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-title">
    <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    </span>
    <div>
      <a href="/index"><img alt="PeopleWare SRL" src="/assets/logo-345d236755fdd29efe4113717b59043034744758f71f11618e58672f2e0dbc6b.png" /></a>
    </div>            
  </div>
  <div id="responsive-menu">
```

Would become:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">PeopleWare</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="responsive-menu">
  <div>
    <a href="/index"><img alt="PeopleWare SRL" src="/assets/logo-345d236755fdd29efe4113717b59043034744758f71f11618e58672f2e0dbc6b.png" /></a>
  </div>
```

Unless you are actually trying to get the Image on the responsive menu.

Anyway, I got the rest of the problems to go away using the console:

```
$(document).foundation()
```

With Zurb you need to tell the javascript to execute.  Once that was run I could toggle the menu.  You problably need in your coffeeScript somewhere

```
$ ->
  $(document).foundation()
```

This will wait until dom ready and run foundation.

Comment: Thanks Andy for you help. The documentation doesn't have that info.

Comment: [gem documentation](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails#add-foundation-to-your-js) is where I found the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I simply set css rule:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
    .title-bar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```